# choose repository when apt-get install

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt-get

I have a raspberry pi and, in the standard repositories, it has zynaddsubfx (a midi sampler). There is a cool guy providing a repository from his own with a version of this same program that is tested on the pi and known to work.

How can I force apt-get to install from this particular repository when he program to be installed has the same name in both repositories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the repo indirectly by giving the exact version you want to install. See this post for a howto: https://superuser.com/questions/124174/how-can-i-specify-the-repository-from-which-a-package-will-be-installed-emacs